# Van Kampen when the there is a cover by finitely many closed sets

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^2$ be a path connected topological space. Suppose we have path connected  closed sets $A,A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_m\subset X$ such that $X=A\cup_{i=1}^m A_i$ where

a) each $A\cap A_j$ is non-empty path connected and a neighbourhood deformation retract in each of $A_i$ and $A$,

b) $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$,

c) $A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j\neq k$.

Is there a version of Van-Kampen theorem that applies to this.
The problem is that there is no base point common to all the sets.

Alternately, I could take $B=\cup_{i}^m A_i$ and $X=A\cup B$ where $A\cap B$ is a union of finitely many path connected spaces (Infact I know that $A\cap B$ is  a union of finitely many circles). In this case can I say something about $\pi_1(X)$ in terms of $\pi_1(A)$ and $\pi_1(B)$?

I would be grateful for any reference.

Comment: c) is a consequence of b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another question which shows the advantage of moving from groups to groupoids, with the notion of the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(X,S)$ on a  **set** $S$ of base points, chosen according to the geometry. In the case presented, choose $S$ to consist of one point $s_i$ in each $A \cap A_i$. For more see the books [Topology and Groupoids](https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf) or [Categories and Groupoids](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/7/tr7abs.html). The second book has more on the use of the algebra of groupoids. The first editions of these books were published in $1968$ and $1971$ respectively.  Essentially, you are computing $\pi_1(X,S)$ for $X$ given as a succession of  adjunction space $A \cup_{f_i} A_i $ where $f_i: A \cap A_i \to A$.

Thus the "natural" answer is in terms of  groupoids.  Compare [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one) mathoverflow discussion.

Of course group theory has been a major part of mathematics and its applications for more than two  centuries, but the extension of the realm of discourse to groupoids is useful for giving algebraic models in topology and  has many applications, including "higher dimensional groupoids", which get more complicated with increasing dimension.

Comment: since $A\cap A_1$ is path connected, I can compute the fundamental group of $A\cup A_1$ at a base point on $A\cap A_1$. Since $A\cup A_1 $ is path connected, it's fundamental group is independent of basepoint. Now $(A\cup A_1)\cap A_2$ is path connected so I can find the fundamental group of $A\cup A_1\cup A_2$. Is this process okay?

Comment: The term "independent of base point" is commonly used but is imprecise - it is also for me like saying every vector space has to come with a basis. Grothendiek wrote to me "`....  the choice of a base point, and the 0-connectedness assumption, however innocuous they may seem at first sight, seem to me of a
very essential nature."  I realise that topology texts generally ignore what can be done with the algebra of groupoids, and even write  about "the fundamental group of a path connected space".